# class or library to parse RRULE of iCalendar

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, icalendar, rfc5545, rrule

Any class or library in VBScript or asp classic that I can use to parse RRULE (iCalendar - RFC 5545) and generate a list of Upcoming Events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with [rrule.js](http://jakubroztocil.github.io/rrule/) , is a javascript library , If you send RRULE string like

```
FREQ=DAILY;DTSTART=20150409T030000Z;UNTIL=20150511T025900Z;WKST=MO;BYDAY=MO,WE,FR
```

the library show a grid with all recurring events.